# PHP JpGraph -- dynamic image creation in same directory for multiple users

Tags: php, jpgraph, high-traffic

I have a PHP page (results.php) that has logic like this:

```
// check if user is logged in

// Get user data from database

// Do stuff with user data 

// use JpGraph to graph user data, save graph.jpg to /directory/

// echo "<img src='/directory/graph.jpg'>"
```

I will be getting approximately 20000 unique visitors within a span of a few days. If two users access results.php at the same time, is it possible that they may see the wrong graph.jpg? (i.e. Alice and Bob go to results.php and they see eachother's graph.jpg when they're supposed to see their own)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: why not create the file with an identifier, such as UID (ie: graph_#UID#.jpg) or something to ensure that you don't have collision because theoretically as stated it can occur.

Comment: Thanks kitty and guardian. I will append the UID to the image so that I don't have a collision.